# Access firestore non public collection with angular/fire

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire

Assume there are 2 firestore collection `public` and `nonpublic` with the following rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /public/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
    match /nonpublic/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

So I can request public data in `angular/fire` via:

```
  firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore)
  items$: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor() {
      const aCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'public')
      this.items$ = collectionData(aCollection);
    }
```

Request `nonpublic` will throw an error.

When implement a provider to register a user e.g. via `registerUserWithPassword` and registration and sign-in was successful, then... How to request a collection with permission for sign-in users? How to access `nonpublic` collection with that user (s.th. like `collection(this.firestore, 'nonpublic', currentUser)`)?

Can someone explain how firestore request will work after user sign-in?

Comment: As Doug said below, you shouldn't need to do anything special. Firebase SDKs already communicate the currently signed in user with each other so that it's available in your security rules. If you can't get this to work, edit your question to show the [minimal code of how you sign in the user and then cal Firestore](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), making sure in your code to prove right before calling Firestore that it's meeting the requirement of your security rules (so: if (`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to request a collection with permission for sign-in users?

You don't have to do anything different.  The Firestore SDK automatically uses the credentials of the currently signed in user in all queries while that user is signed in.